# Часто ли используются медиа-запросы для черно-белых устройств?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Их везде описывают, но так ли они хорошо [работают](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294817/media-queries-color-monochrome-and-printing)?
Вопрос был задан 7 лет назад. Изменилось ли что-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За это время появилсь пара моделей книжек на электронных чернилах, у которых довольно высокий DPI и в то же время есть андроид, брузер и доступ в сеть. Но по сути эти устройств остаются довольно экзотичными. То есть, если бы вопрос был "переделывать ли существующий сайт с учетом доступа с такой книжки" мой ответ был бы "однозначно нет"

Вообще, я подумал еще немного над вопросом, и мне кажется, самое полезное для нестандартных устройств - это версия сайта без анимации. На электронных чернилах она "вообще никак"